# XPath not working as I'd expect it to

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, python-requests, lxml

Hopefully, you don't need the entire set of code here, but I have an issue where I'm parsing HTML, using XPath and I'm not getting what I'd expect:

```
# here is the current set of tags I'm interested in
 html = '''<div style="padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;">
        <a href="http://www.amazon.com/review/R41M1I2K413NG/ref=cm_aya_cmt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B013IZY7RU#wasThisHelpful" ><img src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/communities/discussion_boards/comment-sm._CB192250344_.gif" width="16" alt="Comment" hspace="3" align="absmiddle" height="16" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.amazon.com/review/R41M1I2K413NG/ref=cm_aya_cmt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B013IZY7RU#wasThisHelpful" >Comment</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="http://www.amazon.com/review/R41M1I2K413NG/ref=cm_cr_rdp_perm" >Permalink</a>'''
```

I'm trying to get the `href` value of the first `a` tag, which is a long URL. To do so I'm using the following code

```
from lxml import etree
import StringIO

parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(html), parser)

style = 'padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;'
xpath = "//div[@style='%s']" % style
xpath += "/a[1]/@href"

# use the XPath expression above to pull out the href value
tree.xpath(xpath)


['http://www.amazon.com/review/R41M1I2K413NG/ref=cm_aya_cmt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B013IZY7RU#wasThisHelpful']
```

This works when I pull out the part I'm working with and paste it as a string. This doesn't work exactly the same with the `tree` I've built using a `request.get()` call and I cannot figure out why? What it returns is:

```
['http://www.amazon.com/review/R41M1I2K413NG]
```

And I cannot figure out why. I understand I'm shooting in the dark here, but I'm just hoping someone has come across a "XPath return value of attribute truncated" issue.

**EDIT:**

Here's the full code that I'm currently using, but it doesn't work. It returns the truncated value above.

```
from lxml import etree
import requests
import StringIO
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter


session = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[502, 503, 504])
session.mount('http://www.amazon.com', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding=encoding)

url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/ARPJ98Y7U8K5H?ie=UTF8&display=public&page=3&sort_by=MostRecentReview"
page = session.get(url, timeout=5)
tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(page.text), parser)

style = 'padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;'
xpath = "//div[@style='%s']" % style
xpath += "/a[1]/@href"

# use the XPath expression above to pull out the href value
tree.xpath(xpath)
```

**EDIT 2:**

This does work for some reason. Rather than creating a `session` object and, using that to submit a `get` request, then pass that to the `parser`, simply passing the `url` string to the `parser` works:

```
url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/ARPJ98Y7U8K5H?ie=UTF8&display=public&page=3&sort_by=MostRecentReview"


tree = etree.parse(url, parser)



for e in tree.xpath("//div[@style='padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;']/a[1]/@href"):

    print e
```

As I understand it, when looping through multiple url's the session object will persist connection attributes that speed up the process. If I use the `etree.parse(url, parser)` method, I'm worried I'll lose efficiency.

Comment: How can we reproduce this? Please show us the exact code that returns the truncated attribute value.

Comment: What is the URL you are using when calling `request.get()`?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/ARPJ98Y7U8K5H?ie=UTF8&display=public&page=3&sort_by=MostRecentReview

Comment: While you are doing way more work than needed both blocks of code work fine for me, the only way it would not work is because of some encoding issue,f never call `.text` when using requests, always use `.content` and let requests handle the encoding

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thanks for the feedback. By "more work", what do you mean. I'd like it as streamlined as possible b/c I have thousands of similar url's to scrape. Regarding encoding, I'm not sure yet, but definitely cuts off anything in a url after (and including) `ref=....`.

Answer (score 0):

With the URL you provided, the following Python code:

```
url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/ARPJ98Y7U8K5H?ie=UTF8&display=public&page=3&sort_by=MostRecentReview"

from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = etree.parse(url, parser)

for e in tree.xpath("//div[@style='padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;']/a[1]/@href"):

    print e
```

Results in the following output:

```
> python ~/test.py 

http://www.amazon.com/review/RM8YYCQ57K2CL/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00J9PAZIO#wasThisHelpful
http://www.amazon.com/review/R41M1I2K413NG/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B013IZY7RU#wasThisHelpful
http://www.amazon.com/review/R3DT6VUDGIT9SK/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B000VYD0MA#wasThisHelpful
http://www.amazon.com/review/RGFW1JM4151MW/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00TQQN5G0#wasThisHelpful
http://www.amazon.com/review/R3I9FFX0MVF1BW/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0048A7NF8#wasThisHelpful
http://www.amazon.com/review/R24TTSQY34VME8/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0115ZHH68#wasThisHelpful
http://www.amazon.com/review/R3C49WWMNQZ007/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00ABAWHJ6#wasThisHelpful
http://www.amazon.com/review/R37724EHW829NB/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00TO5Y3FK#wasThisHelpful
http://www.amazon.com/review/RQKGM5FRXVYSX/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0051QUWKG#wasThisHelpful
http://www.amazon.com/review/R1DW61PMGUDMDJ/ref=cm_aya_cmt/159-5911033-5890330?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B000N8Q2P6#wasThisHelpful
```

Using the sample code you provided results in:

```
http://www.amazon.com/review/RM8YYCQ57K2CL
http://www.amazon.com/review/R41M1I2K413NG
http://www.amazon.com/review/R3DT6VUDGIT9SK
http://www.amazon.com/review/RGFW1JM4151MW
http://www.amazon.com/review/R3I9FFX0MVF1BW
http://www.amazon.com/review/R24TTSQY34VME8
http://www.amazon.com/review/R3C49WWMNQZ007
http://www.amazon.com/review/R37724EHW829NB
http://www.amazon.com/review/RQKGM5FRXVYSX
http://www.amazon.com/review/R1DW61PMGUDMDJ
```

This is due to the fact that none of the URLs in the HTML page returned by `session.get()` have any GET parameters; either because the server doesn't return URLs with GET parameters in this case or because `requests` strips off the GET parameters.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm doing....I'll have to come back to it with fresh eyes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, when I use the `etree.parse(url, parser)`, it works. However, if first get the HTML from a `session.get(url)`, and pass the `text` attribute, like `etree.parse(page.text, parser)`, then I get my incorrect result. I want to use the `session.get()` b/c it helps keep the connection between requests.